# SAS- Combining multiple variables into one by choosing the maximum value

Tags: sas

Combining multiple variables into one by choosing the maximum value

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
1  1  2  5  3  1  1
2  4  2  3     5  1
3  3     2  2  1  3
4  2  1  2  5  7  
5  6  7  1  2  1  7
```

into  `n1=max(v1,v2)`, `n2=v3`, `n3=max(v4,v5,v6)`

```
id n1 n2 n3
1  2  5  3
2  4  3  5
3  3  2  3
4  2  2  7
5  7  1  7
```

How do I do this in SAS? (It's so easy in excel.. It's relatively intuitive in R.. But I can't figure it out in SAS! Please help!)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MAX function is your friend.

```
data want;
set have;
n1 = max(of v1 v2);
n2 = v3;
n3 = max(of v4 v5 v6);
run;
```

Arrays and variable lists also work (such as, `n3 = max(of v4-v6);`).

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the [MAX](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245913.htm) function is what you want, but I would code it differently.

```
data want;
set have;
n1 = max(v1, v2);
n2 = v3;
n3 = max(v4, v5, v6);
run;
```

Alternatively:

```
data want;
set have;
n1 = max(v1, v2);
n2 = v3;
n3 = max(of v4-v6);
run;
```